# Unix shell programming to count number of active user using Korn shell

Tags: shell, unix, grep

What is the shell script to count number of logged in user who are using Korn shell currently using grep and any other Unix command. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) including the link "How to ask questions the smart way."

Comment: There is no one shell script for the job.  The real question is: what did you try and what are the problems you're having with it?  In your scenario, are logged in users automatically active?  (I have a machine where I logged in a year ago on one terminal; that terminal hasn't been used in the last 6 months — would it count as active?)

Comment: Yes, I would like to count those as active. @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 0):

`who` is a command that lists users who are online. In order to count the number of online users, you can pipe the output of `who` to `grep`, which can count the number of lines with the `-c` argument:

```
who | grep -c .
```

EDIT: I missed the detail about users using Korn shell.

You can try this instead:

```
ps -e -o command | grep -c "[k]sh"
```

`ps` is a command that lists information about current running processes. The `-e` argument makes it show information about all system processes and the `-o command` arguments makes it shows only commands.

`ps -e -o command` will show you a list of currently running processes. Now, you can pipe the output to `grep` and count the number of lines that match `[k]sh` using the `-c` argument. Brackets are used around the "k" because otherwise `grep` will match itself, as the `grep` command contains "ksh" as an argument. (You can see this by checking the output of `ps -e -o command`.)

(I am assuming that the name of the Korn shell process is "ksh". If it is something else, you should using that as the argument for `grep`.)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to find the count of currently using Korn shell using grep and any other Unix command.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that detail. I just edited the answer to fully answer your question.

Comment: Thanks, that make sense.